# Javascript arrays and functions

Tags: javascript

ok, here is my code below.  I can get it to write out q in the ordered list but what I need to do is get to populate the entered value from the end user for the grocery list.  Then as you can read I need a option for the user to hit q or Q to quit when finished entering items/values.  If they hit quit before entering any values for this list I need some sort of

tags to say "sorry dude, your list is empty."  Any suggestions?

```
document.write('<h1>My Grocery List</h1>');

var groceries = getGroceries();
printGroceries(groceries);

function getGroceries() {
 var canExit = false;
 var items = (prompt);

do {
items = prompt("Enter an item to add to the grocery list (enter \‘q\’ to quit):");
} while (items != 'q' && items != 'Q') 


        canExit = true;

return items;
}

function printGroceries(groceryItems) {
var groceryitems = i;
var msg = '';
msg += '<ol>';

for(var i = 0; i < groceryItems.length; i++) {
msg += '<li>' + groceryItems[i] + '</li>';
}

document.write('<p>Here\'s your grocery list:</p>' + msg + '</li>');

    }
```

Comment: I seem to miss a question? or should we debug first to see what is wrong? Or is the any suggestions, the question?

Comment: My question is how do I get the users information such as a list like milk, cheese, meat, beer to populate instead of just 1.  q  and if they hit q or Q then how do I get it to respond saying sorry dude your list is empty?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle I did for you which should do what you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/Delorian/un9ph61m/

The main change was having one variable for each item and one for the array.

If you want to print it out directly to the page as per your comments below, the code will be like this:

```
var groceries = getGroceries();
printGroceries(groceries);

function getGroceries() {
    var canExit = false;
    var items = [];
    var item = null;

    do {
        if (item !== null)
            items.push(item)
        item = prompt("Enter an item to add to the grocery list (enter \‘q\’ to quit):");
    } while (item != 'q' && item != 'Q') 

    canExit = true;
    return items;
}

function printGroceries(groceryItems) {
    var msg = '';

    if (groceryItems.length > 0)
        for(var i = 0; i < groceryItems.length; i++)
            msg += '<p>' + groceryItems[i] + '</p>';
    else
        msg = '<p>Sorry dude, your list is empty!</p>';

    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = '<h1>My Grocery List</h1><p>Here\'s your grocery list:</p>' + msg;
}
```

Comment: It pulled up a prompt box asking to  enter an item but that is all.  Entered Items and q/Q and nothing

Comment: ok it works on your link but how would I get all of this on an external js file only?

Comment: You can copy-and-paste the JS code in the bottom-left panel into your .js file and it will run once you add a link to that on your HTML page. on your HTML page, you need an element with an id of 'grocery-list' as I did with a paragraph tag on the top-left panel.

Comment: Delorian, I cant have anything on the HTML only the js page.  So how would I accomplish this? Here is my html and what it should look like<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Grocery List</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8"> 
   <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
  
</head>
<body>



</body>
</html>

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
 <title>Grocery List</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8"> 
 <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="js/script.js"></script>
  
 </head>
 <body>



 </body>
 </html>

Comment: I've updated the code above in my answer with how you want it to work. I've also updated the JS Fiddle.